# Prediction view is under keyboard keys

Tags: ios, keyboard, uikeyinput

I have an UILabel subclass, conforming UIKeyInputs protocol. But when the keyboard is shown, prediction view is under keyboard keys: Here is the screenshot:

[image: screnshot]

And here is the implementation:

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {
    // some implementation, nothing important to effect keyboard.
}

extension CustomLabel: UIKeyInput {

  var hasText: Bool {
    if let text = self.text {
      return text.isEmpty
    }
    return false
  }

  func insertText(_ text: String) {
    self.text?.append(text)
  }

  func deleteBackward() {
    guard let text = self.text else { return }
    self.text = String(text.dropLast())
  }

  override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
  }

  private var autocapitalizationType: UITextAutocapitalizationType {
    return .none
  }

  private var autocorrectionType: UITextAutocorrectionType {
    return .no
  }

  private var spellCheckingType: UITextSpellCheckingType {
    return .no
  }

  private var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType {
    return .twitter
  }

  private var returnKeyType: UIReturnKeyType {
    return .done
  }

  private var keyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearance {
    return .default
  }

}
```

One thing that I did not understand is autocapitalizationType, autocorrectionType and other protocol methods for keyboard appearance are not called.

I hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: How did you resolved this problem?

Comment: My way was not to use UILabel, just playing with UITextView. Now, I will check @EvGeniyIlyin ‘s answer.

Answer (score 0):

for `Swift4` you must use `UITextInputTraits` as

```
@objc var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType = .default
@objc var autocorrectionType: UITextAutocorrectionType = .no
```

or

```
@objc  var keyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearance {
    get { return .dark }
    set(value) {}
}
```